# WebBrowser - Click Dialogue Button

Tags: c#, javascript, webbrowser-control

I am using the .NET WebBrowser control to automate some web tasks, however now and again the website I am visiting will produce a dialogue box with a YES/NO button that I need to press.

The dialogue is popped up using a Javascript modal window. I need the WebBrowser to detect a Javascript modal popup, get the source of the popup to define the response to give, and then click one of the buttons.

Can this be achieved?

Comment: send me your code or tell me your requirements like you want YES/No type dialog box and you want to perform operation on click on YES and No buttons.

Comment: Have you managed to click any button in a web browser control with code? If not then I doubt this will be possible.

Comment: @Nunners I have managed to click other buttons with no problem, I just don't know how to interact with a JS dialogue popup box

Comment: @johndyas, is it a real modal dialog window, which blocks the browser window and which you can drag outside the web browser window, all over the desktop? I.e., a window created with `window.alert()` or `window.confirm()`?

Answer (score 0):

I've encountered a similar situation

But in my case it is just a simple confirm dialog so I simply skip it by removing the confirm javascript command from the html element.

Here's the javascript code that invoke the dialog

```
       confirm('Comfirm to kill');
```

here's the full html tag of the button that invoke the dialog

```
       <a id="inputID" onclick="return confirm('Comfirm to kill.');" href="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$ContentMainContent$gvOnlineUser$ctl02$btnAction','')">
```

And here I remove the js to call the function

```
        HtmlElement elementButton = doc.GetElementById("inputID");
        elementButton.SetAttribute("onclick", "return true;");
        elementButton.InvokeMember("Click");
```

That should skip the confirmation dialog part 
I'm not sure it would work in your case though
Hope this help anyway